# How can I put images to IOS device in application folder?

Tags: ios, file, xamarin, xamarin.ios, filesystems

I'm developing the app that need to work with images in app folder (using xamarin, visual studio). How can I put images to app folder avoiding downloading from internet? Finaly the application will download images from the server, but do not want to bother with it for testing and debugging.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/

Comment: I'm know how to work with images. I don't know how can i add images (or other files such as .db file) on ios device in app directory not programmaticaly (for example android device opens like flash drive on PC amd i can easily put files in any directory). Is there any way for ios devices?

Comment: you can save images to the default camera in iOS and can select from there

Comment: @FahadRehman thank you! So, can I use this way for files?

Comment: you can not save files in Camera, you can only save the pictures and videos. If you wanted to use files then you have to put it in you app folder.